# ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed for MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, imagemagick, minimagick

On Windows, I am trying to use the MiniMagick gem in CarrierWave. But when I use it to get dimensions of image in a rails project (in G:Ruby/RailsProject). The following is printed

```
ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed
```

I have installed the latest version of ImageMagick (7.0.3-4). And added the paths:

```
CPATH C:\ImageMagick\include
LIBRARY_PATH C:\ImageMagick\lib
PATH C:\ImageMagick
```

But for some reason. ImageMagick is not detected

Comment: I don't know MiniMagick, Ruby or CarrierWave, so I am only guessing... maybe the `PATH` should be `C:\ImageMagick\bin`

Comment: For some reason, It doesn't exist in my ImageMagick Directory. However, there is a dll version and a binary version. Could it be that only the binary version has bin?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Problem after updating gems- it seems that MiniMagick now forgets:

> Default CLI is ImageMagick, but if you want to use GraphicsMagick, you
>   can specify it in configuration:
>
> MiniMagick.configure do |config|   config.cli = :graphicsmagick end

but puting `config.cli = :imagemagick` in config seemed to solve my problem